# python3 greek letters not showing properly

Tags: python-3.x, decode, encode

I develope a small python program in my rasp zero with lcd touch screen.

Short story:my rasp has attached with a lcd touch screen and a barcode scanner. When someone pass the card from the scanner the programm send the barcode to my mssql server and ask the info. The result are words (lastname and firstname) with greek characters.
BUT the data I get from cursor are not showing properly

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
....some code........
print("Barcode found")
for row in result:
    last_name = row[1].encode('utf-8')
    print('Last Name: ' + str(last_name))
    first_name = row[2]
    print('First Name: ' + str(first_name))
```

as result in print function I get

```
Last Name: b'\xff\xfe\xcd\x00\xd4\x00\xc1\x00\xcd\x00\xcf\x00\xd3\x00'
First Name: ÄÁÕÉÄ-ÂÁÓÉËÅÉÏÓ
```

and the desire output is:

```
Last Name: ΝΤΑΝΟΣ
First Name: ΔΑΥΙΔ-ΒΑΣΙΛΕΙΟΣ
```

Any ideas? I can't understant exactly the principle of decoding or encoding.
Thnx in advance.

Comment: Is `Last Name` or `First Name` the action that you want taken?

Comment: The results come from the same cursor. I just post that the result with .encode('utf-8) and without they come wrong, Last name and first name are in greek.

Comment: Something like `ΝΤΑΝΟΣ ΔΑΥΙΔ-ΒΑΣΙΛΕΙΟΣ`? Please  [edit] the question and update your [mcve].

Comment: Exactly that one. What I have to do ?